# How to access the value of a field in a tracing span?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I'm using the [tracing](https://docs.rs/tracing/0.1.25/tracing/) library in my project and there is one thing I'm not able to figure out: How can I access a value (that I set in my span when I create it) in my [`Layer`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.0.1-alpha.2/tracing_subscriber/layer/trait.Layer.html)?

My layer looks like this:

```
impl<S> Layer<S> for CustomLayer where S: Subscriber {
    fn register_callsite(&self, metadata: &'static Metadata<'static>) -> Interest {
        Interest::sometimes() //hardcoding so enabled() will be called everytime a span is created
    }

    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata<'_>, ctx: Context<'_, S>) -> bool {
        if metadata.is_span() {
            // How do I access value of key here?
            if value == X {
                true
            } else if value == Y {
                false
            }
        }
        true // default
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the data in a `Span` if you have access to either its `ValueSet` (as found in `new_span()` or `on_new_span()` via `Attributes`) or a `Record` entry for it (as found in `record()` or `on_record()`). With that you can use the visitor pattern to find the information you desire. Here's a simple implementation that checks if a field exists and its value is a matching string:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use tracing::field::{ValueSet, Visit, Field};
use tracing::span::Record;

struct MatchStrVisitor<'a> {
    field: &'a str,
    value: &'a str,
    matched: bool,
}

impl Visit for MatchStrVisitor<'_> {
    fn record_debug(&mut self, _field: &Field, _value: &dyn Debug) {}
    fn record_str(&mut self, field: &Field, value: &str) {
        if field.name() == self.field && value == self.value {
            self.matched = true;
        }
    }
}

fn value_in_valueset(valueset: &ValueSet<'_>, field: &str, value: &str) -> bool {
    let mut visitor = MatchStrVisitor { field, value, matched: false };
    valueset.record(&mut visitor);
    visitor.matched
}

fn value_in_record(record: &Record<'_>, field: &str, value: &str) -> bool {
    let mut visitor = MatchStrVisitor { field, value, matched: false };
    record.record(&mut visitor);
    visitor.matched
}
```

This is pretty rudimentary but hopefully demonstrates what is possible. One thing to note is that the "value" that is stored is either a primitive value (`i64`, `u64`, `bool`, `str`, etc.) or in a type-erased form via `&dyn Debug`. Those are the only types of values you can receive from the visitor.

---

Addressing OP's case in particular, as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/issues/1293) you cannot access this information in the `enabled()` method since that occurs before any values are recorded. You will need to make your determination in the `new_span()` method, and use [span extensions](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/registry/struct.SpanRef.html#method.extensions) via the registry to track whether you consider the span is "enabled" in your other methods.

Here's another rudimentary example:

```
use tracing::span::Attributes;
use tracing::{Subscriber, Metadata, Id, Event};
use tracing::subscriber::Interest;
use tracing_subscriber::layer::{Context, Layer};
use tracing_subscriber::registry::LookupSpan;

struct CustomLayer;
struct CustomLayerEnabled;

impl<S> Layer<S> for CustomLayer where S: Subscriber + for <'a> LookupSpan<'a> {
    fn register_callsite(&self, _metadata: &'static Metadata<'static>) -> Interest {
        Interest::sometimes()
    }

    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata<'_>, _ctx: Context<'_, S>) -> bool {
        metadata.is_span()
    }

    fn on_new_span(&self, attrs: &Attributes<'_>, id: &Id, ctx: Context<'_, S>) {
        if value_in_valueset(attrs.values(), "myfield", "myvalue") {
            ctx.span(id).unwrap().extensions_mut().insert(CustomLayerEnabled);
        }
    }

    fn on_event(&self, event: &Event<'_>, ctx: Context<'_, S>) {
        let span_id = event.parent().unwrap();
        if let None = ctx.span(span_id).unwrap().extensions().get::<CustomLayerEnabled>() {
            return;
        }

        // ... rest of your logic
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: I've completely rewritten this answer taking info from the comments and my newfound experience.</sup>

Comment: There is a way to do this. Check [this](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/issues/1293). I wish I could some how get my type (something other than `i64`, `u64`, etc.) but I guess that would be entering Rust territory not tracing.

Comment: And speaking of trait objects, Im willing to downcast. At least for my usecase, I can take that hit because I store my state in the layer. So I wont be downcasting everytime I get that key only the first time.

Comment: Can you expand on the way to do this? The link you note isn't very clear to me.